# How to troubleshoot a timed out error on putty when connecting with ssh on an azure virtual machine

Tags: ssh, debian, azure, virtual-machines, putty

I just came out with a nice ***Debian 9 "Stretch"*** Virtual Machine hosted with ***Microsoft Azure***. I've already used ***PuTTY***, *PuTTYgen* and *Pageant* to connect with ssh to it and i've saved all this configuration into the PuTTY's startup window.

Once connected i've managed the VM, created the `authorized_keys` file and copied my public key in it under the `.ssh` directory.

But this afternoon, while running my PuTTY again, it isn't able to reach the VM and throw me a "timed out" connection after some time.

I've already tried :

- Restart the VM via the *Azure Portal*
- Redeploy the VM via the *Azure Portal*
- Running with **and** without Pageant
- Checking over and over the configuration ...

What I can't do :

- Reset user's credentials and ssh configuration thought the Azure Portal (Missing *VMForLinuxAccess* extension)
- Use ***Azure CLI***
- Change VM's configuration (I don't own the VM rights)

Have you any idea how to troubleshoot this problem ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, first thing for sure would be to look at the network traffic and see if you can at least get a TCP connection, there's a good chance that the problem has nothing to do with SSH...

Comment: Thanks you for answering, how should I look at network traffic? Have you any idea about a tool to perform this ?

Comment: Wireshark is probably the most convenient and most widespread, but you do need to have some knowledge of networking (being able to understand if you're managing to connect to a TCP port).

Comment: You could [telnet](https://www.acronis.com/en-us/articles/telnet/) VMpublicIP with port 22 to check if network traffic blocking.

Comment: Theses answers were definitely awesome, but this morning it seems like everything works like a charm (And i've no explanations on it). 
Telnet was surely a good way too !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put comments as an answer.

> Have you any idea how to troubleshoot this problem?

You could [telnet](https://www.acronis.com/en-us/articles/telnet/) VMpublicIP with port 22 to check if network traffic blocking. Also, you can capture the network traffic packages to analyze the network traces between the client and server via tool Wireshark or Network monitor.

Moreover, you can find the [Troubleshoot SSH connections to an Azure Linux VM](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshooting/troubleshoot-ssh-connection)  and [Detailed SSH troubleshooting steps for issues connecting to a Linux VM in Azure.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshooting/detailed-troubleshoot-ssh-connection)